# What is the proper way to add Moqui framework in Intellij IDE

Tags: moqui

At first (for some day), I have practiced Moqui from the command line. Now I want to start with Intellij IDEA. So I add Moqui framework in my project directory and add all the jar files in the runtime/lib directory. But when I compile, it will gave me following errors.

`/org/moqui/impl/pollEmailServer.groovy
Error:(27,1) Groovyc: Modifier 'static' not allowed here.` 
also generate Following error.

`net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Unable to load class net.sf.ehcache.store.DefaultElementValueComparator. Initial cause was net.sf.ehcache.store.DefaultElementValueComparator.<init>(net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration)
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.ClassLoaderUtil.createNewInstance(ClassLoaderUtil.java:100)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ElementValueComparatorConfiguration.createElementComparatorInstance(ElementValueComparatorConfiguration.java:57)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.<init>(Cache.java:797)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.clone(Cache.java:2817)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.clone(Cache.java:170)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.cloneDefaultCache(CacheManager.java:1952)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addCacheIfAbsent(CacheManager.java:1934)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager$addCacheIfAbsent$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.moqui.impl.context.CacheFacadeImpl.initCache(CacheFacadeImpl.groovy:109)
    at org.moqui.impl.context.CacheFacadeImpl.getCacheImpl(CacheFacadeImpl.groovy:71)
    at org.moqui.impl.context.CacheFacadeImpl.getCache(CacheFacadeImpl.groovy:63)
    at org.moqui.context.CacheFacade$getCache.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.moqui.impl.context.renderer.FtlTemplateRenderer.init(FtlTemplateRenderer.groovy:42)
    at org.moqui.context.TemplateRenderer$init.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.moqui.impl.context.ResourceFacadeImpl.<init>(ResourceFacadeImpl.groovy:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at org.moqui.impl.context.ExecutionContextFactoryImpl.<init>(ExecutionContextFactoryImpl.groovy:182)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:186)
    at org.moqui.impl.webapp.MoquiContextListener.contextInitialized(MoquiContextListener.groovy:44)
    at net.winstone.core.WebAppConfiguration.<init>(WebAppConfiguration.java:782)
    at net.winstone.core.HostConfiguration.initWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:282)
    at net.winstone.core.HostConfiguration.addWebAppConfiguration(HostConfiguration.java:190)
    at net.winstone.core.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:111)
    at net.winstone.core.HostGroup.addHostConfiguration(HostGroup.java:115)
    at net.winstone.core.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:85)
    at net.winstone.Server.initialize(Server.java:122)
    at net.winstone.Server.start(Server.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at MoquiStart.main(MoquiStart.java:152)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: net.sf.ehcache.store.DefaultElementValueComparator.<init>(net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2849)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1718)
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.ClassLoaderUtil.createNewInstance(ClassLoaderUtil.java:91)
    ... 56 more
Error initializing webapp context: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Unable to load class net.sf.ehcache.store.DefaultElementValueComparator. Initial cause was net.sf.ehcache.store.DefaultElementValueComparator.<init>(net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration)
ERROR 25/08/14 18:51:20.625 [main]: Error during context startup for webapp webapp
net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Unable to load class net.sf.ehcache.store.DefaultElementValueComparator. Initial cause was net.sf.ehcache.store.DefaultElementValueComparator.<init>(net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration)
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.ClassLoaderUtil.createNewInstance(ClassLoaderUtil.java:100)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ElementValueComparatorConfiguration.createElementComparatorInstance(ElementValueComparatorConfiguration.java:57)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.<init>(Cache.java:797)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.clone(Cache.java:2817)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.clone(Cache.java:170)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.cloneDefaultCache(CacheManager.java:1952)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addCacheIfAbsent(CacheManager.java:1934)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager$addCacheIfAbsent$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.moqui.impl.context.CacheFacadeImpl.initCache(CacheFacadeImpl.groovy:109)
    at org.moqui.impl.context.CacheFacadeImpl.getCacheImpl(CacheFacadeImpl.groovy:71)
    at org.moqui.impl.context.CacheFacadeImpl.getCache(CacheFacadeImpl.groovy:63)
    at org.moqui.context.CacheFacade$getCache.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.moqui.impl.context.renderer.FtlTemplateRenderer.init(FtlTemplateRenderer.groovy:42)
    at org.moqui.context.TemplateRenderer$init.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.moqui.impl.context.ResourceFacadeImpl.<init>(ResourceFacadeImpl.groovy:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at org.moqui.impl.context.ExecutionContextFactoryImpl.<init>(ExecutionContextFactoryImpl.groovy:182)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:186)
    at org.moqui.impl.webapp.MoquiContextListener.contextInitialized(MoquiContextListener.groovy:44)
    at net.winstone.core.WebAppConfiguration.<init>(WebAppConfiguration.java:782)
    at net.winstone.core.HostConfiguration.initWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:282)
    at net.winstone.core.HostConfiguration.addWebAppConfiguration(HostConfiguration.java:190)
    at net.winstone.core.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:111)
    at net.winstone.core.HostGroup.addHostConfiguration(HostGroup.java:115)
    at net.winstone.core.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:85)
    at net.winstone.Server.initialize(Server.java:122)
    at net.winstone.Server.start(Server.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at MoquiStart.main(MoquiStart.java:152)`

I think I have done something wrong. Can you suggest me what is the proper way to add the Moqui framework in Intellij IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to setup inside IntelliJ IDEA is to create a new project based on the Gradle build files (IntelliJ now supports this).

This particular error is happening because the files in the framework/src/main/resources directory are just classpath resources and should be copied into the JAR as-is, not compiled. This groovy file is a script and meant to be interpreted at runtime, not compiled in advance.

Comment: Is this step documented somewhere that I may have missed or is it my lack of knowledge about ways of working of groovy that prevented me to correct this error? Basically, I want to be sure that if it is the former then it better be documented in some readme file or in the Making Apps with Moqui book.

Comment: This is part of the general approach of using runtime compiled scripts for things like services and actions. That is covered thoroughly in the Making Apps for Moqui book. On settings things up for building it comes down to general understanding of Java and whatever tools you are using. The easiest way to go is just use the IDE for editing (set JARs and XSDs for autocompletion and such) and use gradle for building and running locally.